# Get Data from Component.ts Angular 6

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6

I have success to get data from other api, and show with console.log like below :

[image]

And this is my code in dashboard.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { TicketService } from '../../ticket.service';
import {Chart} from 'chart.js';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-dashboard',
 templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.less'],
 encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
 export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
 temp = [];

 constructor(private ticketService: TicketService) {}

 ngOnInit() {
   this.ticketService.getTicket().subscribe((res)=>{
     console.log(res);
  })
 }
```

How should i do if want to get "tot_site" value into my view in dashboard.component.html ?

[image]

```
<div class="kpi">
   <div style="center" class="color-gray">Network activity</div>
   <div class="item">
     <span class="text-xl"></span>
     <span class="text-lg color-gray"> Tickets</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Please help me guys, thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the API response to public variable. You can loop the result in template using *ngFor.

**Component:**

```
public apiData;
ngOnInit() {
   this.ticketService.getTicket().subscribe((res)=>{
     this.apiData = res;
  })
 }
```

**Template:**

```
<div class="kpi">
   <div style="center" class="color-gray">Network activity</div>
   <div class="item" *ngFor="let item of apiData">
     <span class="text-xl"></span>
     <span class="text-lg color-gray"> {{item.tot_sites}}</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: great! work like a charm. thanks @Suresh Kumar Ariya

Answer (score 0):

**Component:**

Declare one variable to store total sites value:

```
total_sites:any;
```

Check whether response contains your array or not and update variable accordingly.

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.ticketService.getTicket().subscribe((res)=>{
     console.log(res);

if(res && res.length){
 this.total_sites = res[res.length-1].tot_sites;
}
  });
```

**Template:**

Bind that variable to your view:

```
<div class="kpi">
   <div style="center" class="color-gray">Network activity</div>
   <div class="item">
     <span class="text-xl"></span>
     <span class="text-lg color-gray">{{total_sites}}</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

It will be better if you can get object in your response instead of array.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have declare `temp` array which you can access that array in your HTML using `{{ temp[0].tot_site }}`

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { TicketService } from '../../ticket.service';
import {Chart} from 'chart.js';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-dashboard',
 templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.less'],
 encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
 export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
 temp = [];

 constructor(private ticketService: TicketService) {}

 ngOnInit() {
   this.ticketService.getTicket().subscribe((res)=>{
     this.temp = res;
     console.log(res);
  })
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="kpi">
   <div style="center" class="color-gray">Network activity</div>
   <div class="item" *ngFor="let item of temp" >
     <span class="text-xl"> {{ item.tot_site }}</span>
     <span class="text-lg color-gray"> Tickets </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help

Comment: sorry actually I forgot add this. before temp

Answer (score 0):

**Define one global variable like this and store the response value.**

*As global variable can be accessed by html.*

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { TicketService } from '../../ticket.service';
import {Chart} from 'chart.js';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-dashboard',
 templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.less'],
 encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
 export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
 temp = [];
 dataset:any;

 constructor(private ticketService: TicketService) {}

 ngOnInit() {
   this.ticketService.getTicket().subscribe((res)=>{
     this.dataset=res;
     console.log(res);
  })
 }
```

*In html you can loop through dataset and display desired value*

```
<div class="kpi">
   <div style="center" class="color-gray">Network activity</div>
   <div class="item" *ngFor="let data of dataset">
     <span class="text-xl">{{data.tot_in}}</span>
     <span class="text-lg color-gray"> {{data.tot_sites}}</span>
     <span class="text-lg color-gray"> {{data.todays_achieve}}</span>
     <span class="text-lg color-gray"> {{data.todays_target}}</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Or if you have only element in response array**

*then store only tot_sites value like this*

```
ngOnInit() {
       this.ticketService.getTicket().subscribe((res)=>{
         this.dataset=res[0].tot_sites;
         console.log(res);
      })
     }
```

*And in html*

```
<div class="kpi">
       <div style="center" class="color-gray">Network activity</div>
       <div class="item" >
         <span class="text-lg color-gray"> {{dataset}}</span>
       </div>
    </div>
```